# Document collection (array of type) return value and parameter in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How to document `Array` return value (and parameters) in JSDoc when array elements can be either of the following:

- A type (e.g. `String`, `Array`).
- An object literal.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're looking for how to document the **type** of objects in an **array**, you want something like this:

```js
/**
 * @param {String[]} aliases
 */
```

Here inside curly-braces the `String[]` is the parameter type: type `String` as array `[]`.

See also *jsdoc-toolkit*, archived wiki page about [@Param tag, Parameter Type Information](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wikis/TagParam.wiki#Parameter_Type_Information):

> Parameter Type Information
>
> Use curly-braces around the expected type of the parameter to document this information.
>
> `/** * @param {String} userName */ function logIn(userName) { // ... }`
>
> Use a pipe symbol to document that multiple types are permitted.
>
> `/** * @param {String|Number} product */`
>
> Use the [] notation after a type to indicate an array of those types.
>
> `/** * @param {String[]} aliases */`

Answer (score 35):

Given a `screenings` parameter:

```js
screenings = [
    {
        timestamp: 1440157537,
        url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787287/1269037',
    },
    {
        timestamp: ...,
        url: ...,
    },
];
```

You can document it one of the three ways:

### Using [`@typedef`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html):

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} screening
 * @property {Number} timestamp - UNIX timestamp.
 * @property {String} url - Booking URL.
 */

/**
 * @param {screening[]}
 */
function positionTimes (screenings) {}
```

When there are multiple functions that use a variation of the `screening` object, you can use a function namespace, e.g.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} positionTimes~screening
 * @property {Number} timestamp - UNIX timestamp.
 * @property {String} url - Booking URL.
 */

/**
 * @param {positionTimes~screening[]}
 */
function positionTimes (screenings) {}

/**
 * @typedef {Object} filterTimes~screening
 * @property {Number} timestamp - UNIX timestamp.
 * @property {String} url - Booking URL.
 */

/**
 * @param {filterTimes~screening[]}
 */
function filterTimes (screenings) {}
```

### Documenting the [properties of the values in an array](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties):

```js
/**
 * @param {Object[]} screenings
 * @param {Number} screenings[].timestamp - Unix timestamp.
 * @param {String} screenings[].url - Booking URL.
 */
function positionTimes (screenings) {}
```

This won't work for describing [`@return`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-returns.html)ed types because the return value doesn't take a name.

### Using a collection definition:

```js
/**
 * @param {Array.<{timestamp: Number, url: String}>} screenings
 */
function positionTimes (screenings) {}
```

An advantage of this approach is that it's a one-liner so you can use it in `@return` declarations, where the second method won't work.

The disadvantage of the collection definition approach is that it doesn't allow describing property values.

Comment: that's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot you help me save a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

Although you may find that the guidance given in some of the other answers works for you, I prefer this syntax:

```
/**
 * @return {Array<String>} ...
 */
```

And in comparison to the guidance others have offered, I think this is closer to your expectation based on the example you give in your question.

Here's great source for information on JSDoc:
https://wiki.servoy.com/display/DOCS/JSDoc+Annotations

Edit: fixed moved link - thanks @hc_dev for noticing

Comment: The IntelliJ syntax highligher is happy with this :)

Comment: But Netbeans is not, giving "Array.,," in highlighter. Reported a bug.

Comment: What about [arrays of objects with keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139970/1269037)?

Answer (score 4):

As per doco [`@returns`](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReturns)

```
/** 
 * @returns {Array} Lines from the file.
 */
function readLines(filepath) {
}
```

[Also see](http://google.com/codesearch#search/&q=%5E.%2a@returns%20%7B.%2aarray%20lang%3a%5Ejavascript%24&type=cs).

Comment: Heh, didn't think of using Code Search. Unfortunate that it'll be shutting down... thanks!

Comment: I don't know why they are taking it down :(

Comment: The "Also see" link in this answer is dead.

Comment: @JonathanChan: this answer is really old and woefully incomplete. Please choose [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139970/1269037).

Answer (score 1):

In **the documentation for JSDoc** on **[http://usejsdoc.org/](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html)** there is an example given for an array with members of type `MyClass`. There are two possibilities. One looks like this:

```
@param{MyClass[]}
```

The other one like this:

```
@param{Array.<MyClass>}
```

Be aware of the `.` between `Array` and `<`.