# How do you document an array of objects as a parameter in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "c917379",
    "email": "jim@bmw.de"

},
{
    "name": "c917389",
    "email": "jane@bmw.de"
}]
```

It is an array of arbitrary length with a number of repeating fields (*I've reduced this to two fields for clarity*). This gets passed into a JavaScript method.

```
/**
 * @param {?}  data
 */
update:  function(data) {...}
```

I was wondering how you would document this in JSDoc. Ie. how would you document the type where the question mark is?

Comment: JSON is what you get when you serialize the data to a JSON text. It is just an array of objects in JavaScript.

Comment: i know. but i am wondering how you would document it in JSDoc. I know JSDoc can document method types, and anonymous objects

Comment: i dont understand your edit. JSON is the javascript representation of a data structure. I think you need at least one mention of JSON in the question

Comment: JSON is *not* "the JavaScript representation of a data structure". It is a separate data format based on a subset of JavaScript.

Comment: You are confusing JSON with object literals (a common mistake). JSON is a data format like XML or CSV. Object literals is a specific syntax structure to define objects in JavaScript source code. They look similar, but are completely different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Document collection (array of type) return value and parameter in JSDoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498975/document-collection-array-of-type-return-value-and-parameter-in-jsdoc)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just figured out the answer to my question :

It would look like this :

```
/**
 *
 * @param {{name:string, email:string}[]}  
 *
 */
```

Comment: how does that scale if you had lots of fields?

Comment: The method is only interested in these two fields. The data object may have other fields, but the requirement is that these two fields exist in the array

Comment: If JSDoc permits it, then, I suggest you add a `, ...` inside that specification

Comment: u mean @param {{name:string, email:string, ...}[]}? Webstorm doesnt like it

Comment: thanks for your help :) in any case my method is only interested in these two values. Not sure what that would bring anyway.

Comment: The intent was to indicate that it's _not an error_ if additional keys exist in those objects.

Comment: @OliverWatkins: To scale you should consider breaking out the object definition to a separate block using [`@typedef`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html).

Answer (score 29):

In **[JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html)** there is an example given for an array with members of type `MyClass`. It looks like this:

```
@param {Array.<MyClass>}
```

So then you can also do like this:

```
@param {Array.<Object>}
```

And then this also makes sense:

```
@param {Array.<{name:string, email:string}>}
```

Comment: Why is this not higher voted? Although the angle brackets are a little weird, I feel that the `[]` format is not easily seen. _Especially_ when it comes to longer cases such as `{a: number, b: string, c}[]}`.

Comment: @mliqu The angled brackets represent a generic type parameter. It's a very common syntax. The [] is represented already by the word Array. You should read Array.<SomeType> as "Array of SomeType" e.g. Array of String, Array of Person.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelLiquori that this syntax is easier to read then the syntax with the square brackets

`@param {Array.<{name:string, email:string}>}`

Answer (score 10):

Since there's nothing intrinsically "special" with your object contents I believe you would just have to declare it as:

```
@param {Object[]} data
```

The alternative would be to declare a "proper" constructor function for your "class", and then replace `Object` with that function name.

This encapsulation might also help other parts of your code ;-)

Comment: this is an ajax callback object, so even if i did send it to a constructor i would like to document the type that i am passing in.

Comment: ah, so you've no opportunity to massage the objects from "plain old data" into something nicer, first?

Comment: yeah i would like to massage it into some object first and just have that as the param {MYMassagedObjects[]}, but refactoring JS is hell, and i dont think they would let me do such a change.

Comment: @OliverWatkins if you happen to be using jQuery and `.done` style callbacks then the `.then` method is a handy means to preprocess results before passing them onto the original callbacks.

Comment: If PHPDoc allows you to document an object like this `@param {{a: number, b: string, c}}` instead of `@param {Object}` then why should you not document an array like this: `@param {{a: number, b: string, c}[]}` instead of `@param {Object[]}`?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the first question that appears on Google, i think that is useful show how to documment an **two dimensional** array.

The default sintax doesn't work, it shows like 'JsDoc sinxtax error':

```
/**
 * @param {Object[][]} a two dimensional array of object
 * */
```

The correct way to signal a two dimensional array is:

```
/**
 * @param {Array.<Array.<Object>>} a two dimensional array of object
 * */
```