# Documenting an array of objects as a parameter of callback function in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, callback, jsdoc

`callback.rows` is array of arbitrary length with a number of repeating fields.

How can I document each field (type, property, description) in `JSDoc`?

Is there possible to apply this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164292/444079)?

Or may be this solution can be accepted:

```
/**
* Get list of all documents
* @param {Function} callback                      Standard callback function
* @param {Error}    callback.err                  Error object if any
* @param {Array}    callback.rows                 Rows list
* @param {String}   callback.rows[0].field1       field1
*/
var myFunc = function (callback) {
   // Function body
}
```

Comment: I always write the parameters of the callback in the description. Who reads the docs anyways :)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`/**@param {string[]} callback.rows*/`

Note that you can put any type there, not just string... Such as

`/**@param {{field1: string}[]} callback.rows */`

Comment: The second option is OK for me

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned the best documentation for your code is unit tests.

In `JSDoc` should be only main parameters documented. I.e. `callback` is `Function`. The last 3 lines should be moved into your unit test.

This art of documentation is more **maintainable** and **provable**.

Extensive `JSDoc`s are hard to *read* and **maintain**. Not all behavior can be documented.

Not all people can correct understand this documentation.
Some people will try to change documentation on your own flavor.