# JSDoc to describe object with dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I looked at [How to document an array of objects in JSDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295263/how-to-document-an-array-of-objects-in-jsdoc) however I have a slightly different problem:

```
{
    1232345345: 'hello',
    1454765456: 'hello'
}
```

my object will contain properties that are timestamps.

What would be the best way of writing this in JSDoc? I came up with the following, but is this correct and valid JSDoc?

```
/**
 * @typedef {{[timestamp: number]: string}} Things
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on JSdoc's [tags-type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) documentation (look at the section on *Arrays and objects (type applications and record types)*, you can define a type as an Object with *number* keys and *string* values:

```js
/**
 * @type {Object.<number, string>}
 */
const x = {
  1232345345: 'hello',
  1454765456: 'hello'
}
```

Comment: Ah superb thank you! I did see this however it didn't click. Do you know if it is possible to name the "number" as you can in TypeScript?

Comment: You can define any other type and then use it instead of number, like `{Object.<CustomType, string>}` - is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah no, in VSCode when using `[timestamp: number]` the intellisense shows `timestamp` when hovering over however when I used your answer it showed `x`. I hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: Ah, understood - I'm not sure if that's possible but good question!

Comment: I got an answer here: https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/issues/657 Currently JSDoc does not support so called `tuples`.