# Describing an array of objects in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I've got a function which takes an array of objects.
Looks like this.

```
myAwesomeFunction([
    {
        name: 'someName',
        next: false,
        test: 'test'
    },
    {
        name: 'nameTwo',
        next: true
    }
]);
```

So far my JSDoc looks like this

```
/**
 * My description
 * @param {Array.<Object>}
 */
```

But how can I describe the object properties, types and descriptions and if they are optional of the object?

Thank you.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Document collection (array of type) return value and parameter in JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498975/document-collection-array-of-type-return-value-and-parameter-in-jsdoc)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[JSDoc @param documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param)

```js
/**
 * Assign the project to a list of employees.
 * @param {Object[]} employees - The employees who are responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employees[].name - The name of an employee.
 * @param {string} employees[].department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function(employees) {
    // ...
};
/**
```

Comment: Updated link: https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html

Answer (score 16):

### Using [typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)

```
/**
 * @typedef AwesomeObject
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {boolean} next
 * @property {string} test
 */

/**
 * @param {Array.<AwesomeObject>} awesomeObjects Awesome objects.
 */
myAwesomeFunction(awesomeObjects) { ... }
```